# Replace multiple click handlers with a single click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, onclick

I'm wondering if it's possible to clean up these click events a bit:

```
$(document)
    .on('click', '.newGameItem', getNewGameItem)
    .on('click', '.startGame', startThisGame)
    .on('click', '.showThisGameInfo', showThisGameInfo)
    .on('click', '.closeThisGameInfo', closeThisGameInfo)
    .on('click', '#api_game_test', testApiGame)
    .on('click', '.nextGame', shiftGames)
    .on('click', '.confirm_cancel', cancelLexTimer)
    .on('click', '.completed_submission', reload)
    .on('turbolinks:load', function() { ... });
```

The first 8 methods in the chain are click events—is there a way in javascript to combine these under one click "umbrella" even though the click events are delegated to different elements

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single `.click` and check the target of the click with the `event` argument:

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {
  var target = event.target;

  if ($(target).hasClass('newGameItem')) getNewGameItem();
  if ($(target).hasClass('startGame')) startThisGame();

  if (target.id == 'api_game_test') testApiGame();

  // etc
})
```

Here is the doc (quite poor) about jQuery's `event.target`: [api.jquery.com/event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target)

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to get away from a big block of *something*, be it `.on` or [GG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42686935/652669). You could always put it in a separate .js file to separate it so it's not cluttering up your code.

```
// in addHandlers.js
function addHandlers(document) {
    document.on('click',...
}
```

This will clean up your code while getting all of that non-essential clutter out of the way while you're doing the fun stuff.